# Find volume of tetrahedron bounded by $x=0$,$y=0$,$z=0$ and the plane $z=1+x-y$.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, volume

I want to find the Volume of a tetrahedron which is bounded by $x=0$,$y=0$,$z=0$ and the plane $z=1+x-y$.

I know I have to find the region formed by the bounds above and then calculate the integral $\int_RzdA$.
My question is how can I work to find the region components which I will use in the integral?

Comment: for y(x) you can use z=0 so that you get y=1+x

Comment: @Socre thank you. Can you please explain why I have to set z=0?

Comment: What is the level curve of the plane z=1+x-y on the x-y plane?

Comment: y=1+x for z=0? ?

Comment: This line is the intersection of the two planes z=0 and y=1+x. If you imagine a slanted plane passing through a horizontal one ( like an x-y plane ) then you get a form of boundary line on the x-y plane this boundary together with the boundary z=0 y=0 and x=0 you would get a closed boundary. Imagine it. Now if the boundary was told to be z=-3 for example, Then y(x) would be the level curve at z=-3.

Comment: I meant the intersection of the plane z=0 and z= 1-x+y on the first line. Could not edit my comment!

Answer (score 3):

HINT.....Do you need to use calculus? The volume of a tetrahedron with neighbouring edge vectors $\underline{a}, \underline{b}, \underline{c}$ is $$|\frac 16\underline{a}\cdot(\underline{b}\times\underline{c})|$$

Comment: Well, calculus in not necessary but I am just trying to understand (in this case) how to do it with calculus. If I find intersection points of plane with axis then I see that $-1\leq x \leq 0$ but I am having trouble finding the function $y(x)$ which I need for the inner integral!

Comment: Did you want me to write another answer, or will you figure it out?

Comment: Truth is I already know y=x+1 for which I set z=0. But I don't quite understand why I have to set z=0 to find y(x). So if u can explain this It would be helpful

Comment: Z varies from 0 on the xy plane up to the plane equation given. These give the limits for the innermost integral. Y varies from the x axis up to the line in the xy plane defining the shape, that is y=x+1. Finally for the outermost integral, x varies from -1 to 0

Comment: Whichever way you do it, the answer is $\frac 16$

Answer (score 1):

**$\text{Geometrical approach}$**:

Notice, the normal distance of the plane $z=1+x-y\iff x-y-z+1=0$ from the origin $O(0, 0, 0)$ $$=\frac{(0)-(0)-(0)+1}{\sqrt{(1)^2+(-1)^2+(-1)^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$$
The given plane plane: $z=1+x-y$ intersects the coordinate axes at $A(-1, 0, 0)$, $B(0, 1, 0)$ & $C(0, 0, 1)$ respectively.

Thus, the tetrahedron $OABC$ has equilateral triangular base $ABC$ whose each side is
$$=AB=\sqrt{(-1-0)^2+(0-1)^2+(0-0)^2}=\sqrt 2=BC=AC$$
Area of $\triangle ABC$ $$=\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}(\sqrt 2)^2=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

Hence, the volume of the tetrahedron $OABC$ bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$ & the plane $z=1+x-y $ is 
$$=\frac{1}{3}\times (\text{area of equilateral triangular base}\ )\times (\text{normal height})$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\times \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)\times \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{6}}$$